# How do points change in a curved surface?

Tags: functions, coordinate-systems, surfaces

[image]

In the middle picture it shows a row of sticks at certain points along a flat surface.  Now in the outer left picture (never-mind the outer right one), when the surface becomes curved the points (sticks) change position.  Are than any mathematical functions that describe how  points transform from flat to curved surfaces and how to find the new position of the point in the curved surface?

Comment: Yes. Describing how "normal vectors" change along a curved surface is the first bit of "surface theory" in differential geometry. If you're serious, I'd recommend Millman and Parker's Differential Geometry book as one that has a pretty clear derivation of this kind of stuff.  Slightly older, a bit more elementary, is Barrett O'Neill's book (Elementary Differential Geometry). I like them both.